# heroku run rake db:migrate Error connecting to dyno

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, database-migration

I am new on ruby on rails. and am trying to deploy my application from my local system to heroku, but when i run *heroku run rake db:migrate*, i get this error msg:
*Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.7855
 !

 !    Error connecting to dyno, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#timeout-awaiting-process*

I've followed the link to the site but i didn't understand what was said there. Please any help as to how deploy it successfully will be much appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Seems like your have no access to `rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com:5000`

Ask your system administrators or internet service provider to allow this address and port for you

This problem solution already described at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#timeout-awaiting-process, but I didn't understand at once too :)

You can check access to necessary resource by `telnet rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com 5000` command

Update:
Recently I encountered with problem when `rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com:5000` is accessible but `heroku run ...` command doesn't work.
In this case command must be modified to `heroku run:detached ...`

It helped me, but interactive utilities like bash will not work because of output will be available only in logs